# WP Acceptance and the composer.json file required

Tags: php, wordpress, unit-testing, docker, composer-php

I am having trouble setting up WP Acceptance and would like some assistance please. In the documentation it states that it is not required to use WP Local Docker so I have the basic required items installed already. https://wpacceptance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#wp-acceptance

**Requirements**
PHP 7.2+, mysqli PHP extension and Docker

Where I run into trouble is installation instructions say to run the command

```
composer config minimum-stability dev
```

I have the composer.phar file and the composer.json file in the root of my plugin however I have no clue what is suppose to be in the composer.json file. Can someone help point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

`Composer.json` just requires the WP Acceptance package. A minimum stability of dev is set since WP Acceptance is beta software.

I would look at the Distributor `composer.json` if you are confused: https://github.com/10up/distributor/blob/develop/composer.json